# Python regexp with optional groups

Tags: python, regex

With Python I need to parse the following string, that can be written in four different ways:

```
:param MyParam: My description [MyValue] {MyGroup}  
:param MyParam: My description [MyValue]  
:param MyParam: My description {MyGroup}  
:param MyParam: My description
```

The expectation is to extract MyParam, My description, MyValue and MyGroup

I tried with the following pattern:

```
^\:param(?P<param>.*)\:(?P<desc>.*)\s*(\[(?P<value>.*)\])?\s*(\{(?P<group>.*)\})?$
```

but in all cases it is too greedy.

Using the following one:

```
^\:param(?P<param>.*)\:(?P<desc>.*) (\[(?P<value>.*)\])? (\{(?P<group>.*)\})?$
```

I get valid results only if there are spaces according to the pattern expectations.
Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Use the non-greedy variants, i.e. `.*?` instead of `.*`.

Comment: BTW, you don’t have to escape the colons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex to parse all the possible combination mentioned in your question:

```sh
^:param\s+(?P<param>[^:]+):\s*(?P<desc>.*?)\s*(?:\[(?P<value>[^]]*)\])?\s*(?:\{(?P<group>[^}]*)\})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y7kHL1/2/)

**RexEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `:`: Match a colon
- `param\s+`: Match text `param` followed by 1+ whitespace characters
- `(?P<param>[^:]+)`: Match 1+ non-colon characters in named group `param`
- `:\s*`: Match a `:` followed by 0+ whitespace characters
- `(?P<desc>.*?)`: Match 0+ of any characters in named group `desc`
- `\s*`: Match 0+ whitespace characters
- `(?:\[(?P<value>[^]]*)\])?`: Optionally match `[...]` and capture inner text in in named group `value`
- `\s*`: Math 0+ whitespace characters
- `(?:\{(?P<group>[^}]*)\})?`: Optionally match `{...}` and capture inner text in in named group `group`
- `$`: End